# Auth0 management api returns unauthorized - invalid token

Tags: single-sign-on, auth0, jwt

I want to check if email address already registered in auth0 user store by call:

```
GET: https://myDomain.auth0.com/api/v2/users-by-email?email=example@example.com
```

And passing authorization header bearer with access token created by :

```
POST : https://myDomain.auth0.com/oauth/token
```

with the following body:

```
{"client_id":"xyzyAH0BU8dLdxxxx4NNpq37iO","client_secret":"aqVUk2du49qVjxxxxxxxxxxxxx2GniPF5nfS36K-N3nixxxxzcPvh","audience":"audience_from_control_panel","grant_type":"client_credentials"}
```

I added the required scope to my api `read:users`

can anyone tell me what I missed?

Comment: Look at your token on jwt.io and see if it has the correct scopes and has the audience like the other user mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In the post request where you generate the token, have you tried changing the `audience` to `https://myDomain.auth0.com/api/v2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the audience value you are mentioned is the default value this is true but we changed it.

Anyway, I tried different api and same issue occurred , I can got the token but when use it I got invalid token.

Comment: You shouldn't use a different API here; only the management audience that @stackoverflow_user mentioned will work. See here: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens

Answer (score 0):

Check if the permission (not sure which one you do need here) is granted on APIs/Machine to Machine Applications.[image]